# Disable or hide "View Library" menu item

Tags: spotfire, spotfire-webplayer

When clicking the "File" menu from the Spotfire Webplayer, there is a menu item called "View Library", is it possible to disable the item or just hide it?

[image: File menu]

Answer (score 0):

there is currently no way to disable this menu item.

in theory you could use the [`set-public-address` command](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire_server/10.1.0/doc/html/TIB_sfire_server_tsas_admin_help/GUID-1168B883-EFAE-4F42-A652-45FF2A7CC143.html) via the config command line interface and change the URL to some other location, but if that isn't a valid URL it could break things. attempt at your own risk and in a dev environment.